# Finding the eigenvalues of a 4x4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have this matrix $A$, so after I did $\det(xI-A)$, I have this

\begin{pmatrix}
        x & 0 & 0 & -x \\
        0 & x & 0 & -2x \\
        0 & 0 & x & -2x \\
          -1 & -1 & -1 & x-1 
        \end{pmatrix}

At this point I'm contemplating taking out an $x$ out of the matrix but there is a $-1$ on the bottom row.  How can I go about row reducing this matrix?

Comment: Laplace expansion along the right column or bottom row should work.

Comment: there is something strange in the fourth century column

Comment: What was $A$?  Your work above does not make sense to me how you could have gotten there.

Comment: I agree that somethng is strange. $x$ should only appears on the diagonal.

Comment: Friends, the original $det(xI-A)$ was this \begin{pmatrix}
        x -1& -1 & -1 & -1 \\
        -2& x-2 & -2 & -2 \\
        -2 & -2 & x-2 & -2 \\
          -1 & -1 & -1 & x-1 
        \end{pmatrix}

Comment: And the original A matrix was this \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
          1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
        \end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A  = \pmatrix {1&1&1&1\\2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2\\1&1&1&1}$

Since A is a singular matrix, we know that 0 is an eigenvalue.

So, what is the dimension of the kernel of A?

if we perform row operations on A we get

$A  = \pmatrix {1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}$

The dimension of the kernel is 3

0 is an eigenvalue of multiplicty 3

The sum of the eigenvalues equals the trace of the matrix.

The trace of A is 6

The remaining eigenvalue is 6